# Assigning read yaml file to variable in browser to be used in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yaml

I am trying to parse a yaml file that exists as a local file in the filesystem and assign it to a variable that can be used in jquery.
I can see from the console.log that _yaml variable contains the read yaml in a readable format but the returning of it and assigning it to ymlconfig does not seem to work (//NOT WORKING part below shows up as undefined in console).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ymlconfig = read_config('config.yaml');
    console.log(ymlconfig["compute"][0]); //NOT WORKING

    function read_config(cfgfile) {
        $.get({url: cfgfile, dataType: "text"}).done(function (data) {
            var _yaml = jsyaml.load(data);
            console.log(_yaml["compute"][0])  //WORKING OK
            return _yaml;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Please read over the text in your question and edit to ask a clear question.  It's hard to understand what the problem is, what you're encountering, and exactly what you're hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string:

```
console.log(ymlconfig["compute"][0]); //NOT WORKING
```

executes before the config is read. Because the called `read_config('config.yaml')` runs asyncronously in the separate thread.

Also your `function read_config(cfgfile)` does not return any value.

To better understand this behaviour please read and run the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var ymlconfig;
   read_config('config.yaml'); // calling function
   console.log(ymlconfig["compute"][0]); // is empty

   setTimeout(function() { // let's wait 2000 ms. hope it's enough to send the request and receive and read the response
      console.log(ymlconfig["compute"][0]); // TADA! It's read.
   }, 2000);

   function read_config(cfgfile) {
      $.get({url: cfgfile, dataType: "text"})
       .done(function (data) {
          ymlconfig = jsyaml.load(data);
      });
   };
});
```

So depending on your task you have several options:

work with the config data within `.done` callback function,
 or make your request syncronous,
or catch the asyncronous response (e.g. using promise)
or maybe something else?

Comment: What do you mean it executes befors the config is read? I am calling the funcion to read it?

”Also your function read_config(cfgfile) does not return any value.” Now that I can understand. I have tried to assign a variable before the get like var test=$.get and return that but not only is it extremely ugly. It also does not seem to work. I am new to JavaScript so these functions within functions seems a bit difficult to return stuff from.

Comment: @nicklas, thank you, I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks a million. That works. I should have realised the asynchronus nature of the request but since I am just loading a local file I expected immediate response.
[inline] `  function read_config(cfgfile) {
   var rawyaml = '';
   $.get({url: cfgfile, dataType: "text", async: false}).done(function (data) {
    rawyaml = data;
    console.log(rawyaml);
   });
   return jsyaml.load(rawyaml);
  };
` [/inline]
Does the job for me.